# Core Analytics API 3 max-results and start-index SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to replicate [this example from the TryMe](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/list?apix_params=%7B%22accountId%22%3A%22157374703%22%2C%22webPropertyId%22%3A%22UA-84036103-1%22%2C%22max-results%22%3A10000%2C%22start-index%22%3A2%7D).

But I would like to include the max-results and start-index

```
property_links = analytics.management().webpropertyUserLinks().list(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
      start-index = 2,
      max-results = 10000
  ).execute()
```

But it's not working. I get the error **SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression**

How do I use the start-index and max-result in the query?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is right or wrong but checked google API. I found some difference between your request and actual google try me example. Please try below syntax. Let see whether it is working or not.

```
gapi.client.analytics.management.webpropertyUserLinks.list({
    "accountId": "157374703",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-84036103-1",
    "max-results": 10000,
    "start-index": 2
})
```